# how to get version number from a file in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have to get the version number of uboot stored in a file. The location of the file is tmp/version.
The output of the file is something like

U-Boot 2011.01 8.5.R02.**149** |armv7_ac3| (Jan 27 2021 - 21:28:06)

The number in bold letters is the version number. I have to store this version number to a variable
I tried

```
uboot = `cat tmp/version`
version = "${uboot:24:27}"
```

but I don't think it is the correct way of doing it. Please suggest if there is any other way of getting the required output

Comment: So what all did you try?

Comment: How about `cat tmp/version | cut -d ' ' -f 3 | cut -d '.' -f 4` ?

Comment: The spaces around = are not allowed.

Comment: How about: `IFS='. ' read -r _ _ _ _ _ _ version _ <tmp/version`?

Comment: `output of the file`?  Files do not produce output; a file is just a sequence of bytes.  Perhaps this is just an English language foible, but there may be a conceptual misunderstanding here as well.

Comment: @HimajaKrishna: _The output of the file..._. Do you mean 'the content of the file' or maybe 'some line in the file'? A program has output; a file doesn't.

Comment: @HimajaKrishna : _ I don't think it is the correct way of doing it._ : Why do you think in so? Except for the syntax errors, your approach is not basically wrong.  _Please suggest if there is any other way_ : There are many ways to do it. I would for instance use pattern matching using a regular expression. See the bash man-page, section **Compound Commands**, and look for the operator `=~`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **I**nternal **F**ield **S**eparator `IFS` environment variable can be set to delimit the different version fields to read from the file.

If you are only interested by the build version, you can skip un-needed fields using `_` as place-holder variable name:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

IFS='. ' read -r _ _ _ _ _ _ version _ <tmp/version
```

Here is how you can collect all of it at once:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

IFS='. ' read -r name year month major minor release build _ <a.txt

# For debug purpose
declare -p name year month major minor release build
```